# Why does my cross-entropy loss function get huge if I use a network of many relus?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

I have this loss function:

```
            loss_main = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(train_logits, train['labels']),
                name='loss_main',
            )
```

`train_logits` is defined from a pipeline built as follows:

```
    def build_logit_pipeline(data, include_dropout):
        # X --> *W1 --> +b1 --> relu --> *W2 --> +b2 ... --> softmax etc...
        pipeline = data

        for i in xrange(len(layer_sizes) - 1):
            last = i == len(layer_sizes) - 2
            with tf.name_scope("linear%d" % i):
                pipeline = tf.matmul(pipeline, weights[i])
                pipeline = tf.add(pipeline, biases[i])

            if not last:
                # insert relu after every one before the last
                with tf.name_scope("relu%d" % i):
                    pipeline = getattr(tf.nn, arg('act-func'))(pipeline)
                    if include_dropout and not arg('no-dropout'):
                        pipeline = tf.nn.dropout(pipeline, 0.5, name='dropout')

        return pipeline
```

The `layer_sizes`, `weights`, and `biases` are constructed like so:

```
    def make_weight(from_, to, name=None):
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([from_, to], stddev=0.5), name=name)

    def make_bias(to, name=None):
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([to], stddev=0.5), name=name)

    layer_sizes = [dataset.image_size**2] + arg('layers') + [dataset.num_classes]
    with tf.name_scope("parameters"):
        with tf.name_scope("weights"):
            weights = [make_weight(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1], name="weights_%d" % i)
                       for i in xrange(len(layer_sizes) - 1)]

        with tf.name_scope("biases"):
            biases = [make_bias(layer_sizes[i + 1], name="biases_%d" % i)
                      for i in xrange(len(layer_sizes) - 1)]
```

If `arg('act-func')` is relu, then if I build a long chain of relus - like with `arg('layers')` being `[750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750]` - then my loss function is huge:

```
Global step: 0
Batch loss function: 28593700.000000
```

If I have a shorter chain of relus - say `arg('layers')` is only `[750]` - then the loss function is smaller:

```
Global step: 0
Batch loss function: 96.377831
```

My question is: **why is the loss function so dramatically different?** As I understand it, the output of the logits is softmax'd to result in a probability distribution. Then the cross entropy is determined from this probability distribution, to the one-hot labels. Why would changing the number of relus I have change this function? I figure each network should be equally wrong at the start - about random - and so the loss would never grow too large.

Note that this loss function does **not** contain any l2 loss, so the increased number of weights and biases would not account for this.

Using `arg('act-func')` as `tanh` instead, this increase in loss does not occur - it stays about the same, as I would expect.

Comment: The cross entropy loss can indeed be unbounded if the model's probability for the correct label is 0. Now, you have to figure out if your model is producing 0 as the probability for the correct label when you see the huge loss. I would try printing out `tf.nn.softmax(train_logits)` to make sure that it is producing approximately `1/number of classes` as the probability at the beginning of training.

Comment: An sttdev of 0.5 is too high

Answer (score 1):

Check outputs of softmax first. If the outputs are like this:

```
[[0., 1.],
 [0., 1.],
 [0., 1.],
 ...
 [0., 1.]]
```

but the ground truth are like this:

```
[[1., 0.],
 [1., 0.],
 [1., 0.],
 ...
 [1., 0.]]
```

then the cross entropy loss would be very big. According to the formula of cross entropy:

```
-[ylog(a) + (1-y)log(1-a)]
```

where ***y*** is the ground truth and ***a*** is the output of softmax.

Sometimes, it is some "huge" feature value, which is not normalized, make these "wrong" output of softmax. According to the definition of softmax:

```
exp(z_j)/sum(exp(z_i)) for i=1 to D
```

where ***D*** is the dimension of vector ***z***, if there are some "huge" components, the output of softmax will almost be 0 or 1.